# Linearly increasing color darkness algorithm

Tags: css, algorithm, function, colors, hex

I want to write a function in ruby that given a number between 1 and 500 will output a 6 digit hex color code that gets linearly darker for higher numbers. This doesn't seem that hard but I'm not sure where to begin.  How can I implement this?

**edit**

Hue seems like a more reliable way to go.  I'd like to give a reference color, say a shade of green, and then darken or lighten it based on the input number.

input: 10
output: color code (in rgb or HSV) that is a light shade of the reference color

input: 400
output: color code (in rgb or HSV) that is a fairly dark shade of the reference color

**edit 2**

The only reason I need to use between 1 and 500 is because that's the input I have to work with.  It's alright if some numbers that are close together map to the same color.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking exactly.  Can you give an example of sample input and output?

Comment: There are only 256 brightness levels available for the gray-scale.  e.g. 0x000000, 0x010101 ... 0xfefefe, oxffffff, so 500 seems a bit pointless.  If you want to change the hue e.g. go from light blue to dark red there are more steps, but you will need to clarify your problem a bit more.

Comment: Are you wanting to make a reference color progressively darker, or would you be happy with a progression from white to black?

Comment: You say that you want to make a "function"... what language would you like this function to be written in?

Comment: Keep in mind sRGB is non-linear.

Comment: Sorry for the inconsistent terminology.  I'm writing this in Ruby.

Comment: A progression from white to black won't work for me.  I need to use a reference color.

Comment: sRGB is non-linear, but so is eye response. They cancel each other out to a large degree.

Comment: Do you need to get lighter than a pure, fully saturated version of the hue? I.E. if your hue is pure green, should an input of 1 return #00ff00 or should it return #fefffe?

Comment: an input of 1 would return 00ff00 then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic linear interpolation?

```
// Pseudocode
function fade_colour(source, factor)
    const max = 500
    const min = 1

    foreach component in source
        output[component] = round(source[component] * (max - value) / (max - min))
    endforeach

    return output
endfunction
```

Comment: @Ransom, Are you sure?  If I input value=1 I get source[component] back, according to Google, and if I input value=500 I get 0.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking - your formula is exactly the same as mine, only more generic. I withdraw my comment.

Answer (score 3):

The 6 digit hex color code is in RGB.
What you want is to work in HSV: pick a Hue and Saturation, and gradually decrease the Value.
Convert from HSV to RGB to output the color.
See [here](http://www.mandelbrot-dazibao.com/HSV/HSV.htm) for an example.

Comment: This looks good. Is there a simple way to convert from HSV to RGB in Ruby?

Comment: @William - Yes, the wikipedia link from Jared Updike shows a simple formula.  All you need is floor, mod, and arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just return a gray level then, #ffffff to #000000?  500 levels of darkness aren't really distinguishable anyway, and grays give you 256 levels.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use a reference color.  Grays won't work for me.

Comment: just divide the number 1 to 500 by 2 and you'll get 1 to 250, which is probably perfect for what you need. (actual math: nuval = oldval * 255 / 500 -- with ints, make sure to multiply before you divide)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to darken your reference color, it's easy.  Given an R,G,B color that is the brightest you want to go, multiply each of the 3 values by (500-input) and divide by 499.  Convert each of the values to 2 hex digits and append them with a # at the front.

Comment: as pointed out elsewhere, this isn't how RGB color works.  HSV is a better color system for this.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the objection. There are other operations that might be easier in another color space, but darkening an RGB color is quite trivial.